# What does it mean to have a compile time dependency from UI layer to Infra layer in clean architecture?

Tags: .net, architecture, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

This is regarding clean architecture. As shown in the below diagrams, the solid arrows represent compile-time dependencies, while the dashed arrow represents a runtime-only dependency.

The idea is that the core layer has got the interfaces and business logic. The infra layer is the implementation of the the persistence layer. The UI layer is the MVC web layer.

**Both the infra layer and the UI layer reference the core layer.** This results in the compile-time dependency. The run-time dependency occurs as part of the DI framework. This is clearly represented in diagram 2.

Diagram 1 is slightly different showing compile time dependency from UI layer to Infra layer (this is not shown in Diagram 2). What does it mean to have a compile time dependency from UI layer to Infra layer **in clean architecture**?

**Diagram 1:**

[image]

**Diagram 2:**

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures

Comment: I diagram 1, the UI layer is linked to the infra layer by an `optional compile-time dependency`, as far as I see

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean to have a compile time dependency

It means that the dependency exists at compile time.  So if you don't have the dependency you can't compile.

It also means that there's a strong connection between one part of your code and another.  This might be ok, but in some situations you might want to avoid that.

It's also more likely that design decisions in the dependency might find their way up into code where they shouldn't be - e.g. infrastructure influencing the UI.

The classic example is database technology and data access code.  Lets say you develop your app's UI and business logic, but you want to implement two different databases - MS SQL and Oracle.  You can develop the necessary data access code into two different assemblies / modules - one for each, but with compile-time dependency you'll have to have them both in-place, and the resulting build will include both Oracle and MS SQL system dependencies.

If you use DI, the dependency only comes into force during runtime, so your builds will be cleaner.

It also means that its much less likely that you'll end up with Oracle or MS SQL specific code in your UI.